# Add to Google Apps Global Navigation without Marketplace

Tags: google-apps

I have built some utilities to be used exclusively by members of our small team. I want them to be available in the Google Apps global navigation, but I can't figure out how to do that without adding them to the Google Apps Marketplace.

Adding to the Marketplace is more complicated than it needs to be (the app I'm creating will never need a support URL, for instance), and I don't want to create a public Google Apps Marketplace vendor profile just for the sake of these small internal tools.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Extensions console:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/index

this allows you to specify just a manifest without needing to go through all the Marketplace work.

Jay